# JAVA avoid duplicate code when casting to sibling classes

Tags: java, inheritance, code-duplication

I have 2 Java classes A and B; they both extend another Java class, C for example. Inside another class I have an object of class C, passed as argument of a method, and I have to use this object (with appropriate cast) to set fields of A and B, such as:

```
if(C instanceof A){
    ((A)C).setAField1(AField1);
    ...
    ((A)C).setAFieldN(AFieldN);
}else if (C instanceof B){
    ((B)C).setBField1(BField1);
    ...
    ((B)C).setBFieldN(BFieldN);
}
```

I have to set the same fields, I have the same calls to setter methods, but I have to do different casts. What do I have to do to avoid code repetitions?

PS: I can't put those fields in C class because it is extended by other classes that don't need them.

Answer (score 1):

**Programming to interface.**

Let all the your classes implement through a interface and then use interface type alter on.

You end up with code like below with no if conditions

```
 yourInterfaceInstance.setField(fieldVar);
```

Comment: Without using interfaces code repetition is the only way?

Answer (score 0):

You may split your method to 2 other methods, one that accepts object of class A, and another one, that accepts of class B. If you need too much to downcast maybe passing object as C is not suitable. It should be great if you define interface for class A methods (interfaceA) and one for B class set methods (say InterfaceB). Thus in your new methods you can pass objects by interface and your code will be extensible. For example :

```
void methodThatWorkWithA(InterfaceA obj) {
  obj.setFieldA1(someValue);
}
```

same for class B.

Answer (score 0):

U can use the concept of interface.

class A extends C   {}

class B extends C  {}

class C implements StackOverFlow {}

interface StackOverFlow{
}

class Test{

// StackOverFlow.setField(field);
}